# How do I add a static dependency to a dll (advapi32.dll) from the cl.exe command line?

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I'm sure there's something simple I'm missing.  I'm running from the Visual Studio Command Prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By linking with the right import library.

Add advapi32.lib to the command line, cl.exe should recognize it as a library to link to.

Comment: Thanks.  After doing that Depends.exe still shows it as a delay-load library.  Is there any way to force it to load and initialize apart from calling a function in it?

Comment: Not that I know. But why would you want to link explicitly to advapi32 if you do not use it ?

Comment: I'm trying to work around a bug caused by calling it from within dllMain.  It's not initialized properly yet so it is failing.

Comment: Well, generally speaking, you should not use delay-loaded libraries or LoadLibrary them from DllMain (see http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/kernel/DLL_bestprac.mspx).

Comment: ... because it can cause deadlocks or crashes.

Comment: How to link with this `Advapi32.lib` library? P.S., I just found it here: `cl t.cpp /link /DEFAULTLIB:advapi32.lib` [linking error LNK2019](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/89a4a707-778f-4e64-96d3-ca4a6c89f709/linking-error-lnk2019?forum=vclanguage)