# Linker error while linking some windows APIs

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registry, linker-errors

I have a makefile project in my system. Recently, I added some new functions which makes use of the following Windows APIs:

```
RegOpenKeyEx
RegEnumKeyEx
RegCloseKey
RegGetValue
```

For having those APIS I added the `windows.h` header file as well.
The code compiles and links fine in my machine. But, linking fails in my colleagues machine. We all are working on 64 bit windows machine.
In his PC I get the error:

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_RegOpenKeyExW
>
> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_RegGetValueW
>
> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_RegCloseKey
>
> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_RegEnumKeyExW

What I tried:
Since the library being used was `Advapi32.lib` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib\x64`

I tried adding following line:

> LINKFLAGS += -L "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib\x64"

I added the path of the library to environment variable `PATH`

I copied the lib to the output folder.

Nothing worked.

As I said earlier, the code works fine in my PC but fails in another one.

Comment: Are you using the same IDE? I had something like this before when for some reason a `#define` was wrong and excluded some functions from the `windows.h`

Comment: @bowdzone it's a linker error

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ...ups

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The registry functions require you to pass `Advapi32.lib` to the linker. This is the step that you have missed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Why is it that it works on my system but not in others? I am new to makefile writing and the file was written by someone else.

Comment: Very hard to say. You did not give details of which compiler you were using. Or what's in the make file. Or what is different between the machines. So no, I cannot suggest a detailed fix.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437875/unresolved-external-symbol-error-occurring-only-in-64-bit-mode-and-not-in-32-bit> could you please check with this thread and ans. 1 in that thread as it solves my issue but  " add "Explicit" exports to the DEF file to get it to work. Must be that the 32-bit was implicitly adding, but the 64 was not." is it the reason Explicit need to add for 64 bit ?

Comment: Note: The command line usage is `cl t.cpp /link /DEFAULTLIB:advapi32.lib` [How do I add a static dependency to a dll (advapi32.dll) from the cl.exe command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155292/how-do-i-add-a-static-dependency-to-a-dll-advapi32-dll-from-the-cl-exe-command)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using visual stdio, check your project property vs your friend's project property and check link library path+ library name with .lib shoul be included. It seems in your friends computer is not getting the library to resolve the symbols. Compile time checking is done only with header files. While linking it should find the definition of yor function in library.

for command line:
from:http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6bcae3d1-85b6-471d-a4ee-7b455b21460b/how-do-i-link-libraries-that-are-sitting-in-different-directories-from-the-command-line?forum=vcgeneral

cl main.obj ab1.lib ab2.lib de1.lib de2.lib gh1.lib /Fetestmain.exe /link /LIBPATH:C:\test\ab /LIBPATH:C:\test\de /LIBPATH:C:\test\gh

**The "/link" is very important...do not use "/LINK", the uppercase LINK is not recognised.**